# How to use a variable inside an XSL select statement?

Tags: xml, xslt, symphony-cms

I am quite new to XSL and I would like to use my variable `$language` inside my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="data">

    <xsl:value-of select="concat(//text-, $language)"/> 

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can this be done?

This is my XML:

```
<data>
  <params>
    <language>en</language>
  </params>

  <static>
    <entry id="1">
        <text-en>Hello</text-en>
    </entry>
    <entry id="2">
        <text-fr>Boujour</text-fr>
    </entry>
  </static>
</data>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the structure of the input XML and use e.g. `<text xml:lang="en">Hello</text>` if you can, then you can write `<xsl:value-of select="//text[lang($language)]"/>`.

If you can't change the structure of the input XML, use `<xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = concat('text-', $language)]"/>`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! I went with the second version because unfortunately I can't change my XML in this case.